# amCharts 5 - pieChart/Donut chart legend Label color change

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0DbC.png)

I have to change legend label color - others, operating and primary to black color.

I have to change legend label color - others, operating and primary to black color, it taking default color which I have given for pie chart/donut chart.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.